# Add customised <option> to all existing <options>s

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this `styled-select` which I made due to my requirements. Now I want to add a customised `<option>` to the bottom of all existing options. The style of this last option is shown below in the picture:

[image: Last Option Image]

The **CSS** referred to this customised option is:

```
.lastOne {
  background-image: url(http://s31.postimg.org/ule20cjtj/left.png), url(http://s31.postimg.org/ydjsauv6f/right.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  height: 28px;
  width: 241px;
}
```

After resolving the problem of not appearing the `class="lastOne"` as expected in my options, I want to know is it possible add this option to my existing options using jQuery?

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/1uudd95x/2/)

```js
 $(function() {

   $('.styled-select select').hide();
   $("select#elem").val('0');

   $('.styled-select div').each(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $(this).html($container.find('select option:selected').text());
   });

   $('.styled-select div').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var opLen = $container.find('select').children('option').length;
     if (opLen < 5) {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', opLen).focus();
     } else {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', 5).focus();
     }
   });

   $('.styled-select select').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var text = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
     $container.find('div').html(text);
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

   $('.styled-select select').focusout(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

 });
```

```css
.styled-select select {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: none;
  width: 241px;
  top: 29px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
}
.styled-select {
  background: url('http://s31.postimg.org/om7atjdqv/campaign_Selector.png') no-repeat right;
  background-color: white;
  height: 28px;
  width: 241px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
  background-position: 97% 50%;
  z-index: 100px;
}
.styled-select option {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 3px;
  width: 241px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.lastOne {
  background-image: url(http://s31.postimg.org/ule20cjtj/left.png), url(http://s31.postimg.org/ydjsauv6f/right.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  height: 28px;
  width: 241px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="styled-select">
  <div id="selectedDivId" style="margin-left: 5px; position: absolute;  width: 210px; top: 4px; height: 28px; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding: 0 30px 0 0; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"></div>
  <select id="fbCampaignId47_502" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].campaignId" style="position: absolute">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="6040224291703">1st</option>
    <option value="6036780606903">2nd</option>
    <option value="6038009946703">3rd</option>
    <option value="6037196648903">4th</option>
    <option value="6038009946123">5th</option>
    <option value="6032323455203">6th</option>
    <option value="6037191235103">7th</option>
    <option class="lastOne"></option>
  </select>
</div>

<div style="height: 150px">
</div>
<div class="styled-select">
  <div id="selectedDivId" style="margin-left: 5px; position: absolute;  width: 210px; top: 4px; height: 28px; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding: 0 30px 0 0; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"></div>
  <select id="fbCampaignId47_502" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].campaignId" style="position: absolute">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="6040224291703">1st</option>
    <option value="6036780606903">2nd</option>
    <option value="6038009946703">3rd</option>
    <option class="lastOne"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `$('select').append('<option class="lastOne">sometext</option>');`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar first of all the problem is that class="lastOne" is not appeared as expected in the options

Comment: element option id getting added at the end of each select, you need to fix the css.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I also changed .lastOne to .styled-select option lastOne but still it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updated working fiddle. i think its solve your problem
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1uudd95x/3/

Comment: Great ! I was on safari and it did not work, but then I tried on Chrome and Firefox it works fine.